# $\alpha\colon I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, with $\alpha(t)\neq 0$ and $\alpha(t) \perp\alpha'(t)$, is necessarily circle?

Tags: differential-geometry

If $\alpha\colon I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is a curve (differentiable map), such that $\alpha'(t)\neq 0$ for all $t$ and $\alpha(t)$ is orthogonal to $\alpha'(t)$ for every $t$ in $I$, then is $\alpha$ necessarily a circle (or connected part of a circle?)?

Comment: No, but the whole trajectory is included in a sphere centered at the origin.

Comment: any example? (visual example? I am beginner in differential geometry)

Comment: Example of what? Of a trajectory included in a sphere?

Comment: as you said alpha is not necessarily a circle, what is example?

Comment: **Any** curve included in the sphere would do.

Comment: ok. thanks for some clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is given by Did in the comment essentially. From your assumption, you have

$$\frac{d}{dt} \|\alpha (t)\|^2 = \frac{d}{dt} \alpha (t)\cdot \alpha (t) = 2 \alpha'(t) \cdot \alpha(t) = 0$$

This shows $\|\alpha (t)\|^2$ is constant, thus $\alpha$ lies in a sphere of some fixed radius centered at the origin. However, $\alpha$ might be **ANY** curves lying in a sphere.